# Yield TakeEvery vs yield All

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Can I use yield takeEvery instead of yield all ? My use case is I want to execute the network request in parallel. The saga documentation says that you can use takeEvery for concurrent requests. Also what’s the difference between takeEvery and yield all